# How to apply the physics fluid properties?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

Can somebody please instruct me on what to do here? I haven't had any results for 2 weeks.

Here's what I've already tried:

1. **Quick Effects** - It doesn't give me the results I'm looking for. Neither can I edit its results into what I want. Why can't I edit the quick effects results? I'm confused.
2. **Physics Tab** - I acknowledge that there's something I'm not doing. I already know that I am supposed to: 1. Go to the PHYSICS TAB 2. Tap on the FLUID MODIFIER and that's as far as I usually get.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
[image: Blender Physics]

**Image 1:** Water Flows From Object A into Object B.

**Image 2:** Water jellies around inside of its container.

I have read the Blender Manual and I'm currently viewing several Blender YouTube Tutorials. I checked my Blender App to make sure that I had the latest version too.

Does anybody have any suggestions or tips? Please let me know.

Comment: Blender doesn't take the emitter settings into account as long as the domain remains the same. In other words, you have to change a parameter on the domain (like resolution for example, just add 1 ) for Blender to consider your new fluid settings.
At least, this is how it works for smoke simulations, which I'm more familiar with, but there is no reason for it to be different here.
This might help : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6B0QM4Cft5c

Comment: Even really nicely organised and illustrated question -what you need, but it is quite hard to understand your specific issue. Like now it sounds nothing works for you. Ad 1 - like mentioned by Karl - if you have  an issue changes in properties does not affect real time simulation - change Resolution +/-1 to ... it is terrible process, but this is a pain for many years in blender. Or Bake a cache. Ad 2 - if you saw some tutorials, I expect you know you need for Liquid Sim two types of objects, one type Domain and one type Flow, right?